# Determine if the map ϕ is an isomorphism of the first structure with the second.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\varphi :\langle \mathbb{Z},+\rangle \to\langle \mathbb{Z},+\rangle$, where $\varphi(n):=3n$.

I need help if anyone can offer it.  I feel kind of lost.  I need to determine if map ϕ is an isomorphism of the first structure with the second and state why it is or why it is not.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\cong n\mathbb{Z}$, for $n\neq 0$ an integer.

Answer (score 4):

To be an isomorphism it must be, among other things, surjective. Can you find $\;n\in\Bbb Z\;$ s.t., for example, $\;\phi(n):=3n=2\;$ ?